# iOS App not launching on iPod touch 5G (but working on iPhone 5)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ipod-touch

My application was accepted to the Appstore and worked on the simulator and on an actual iPhone 5 but my customers are complaining that the application isn't starting on their iPod Touch 5G's.

I use `Xcode 5.1` with `iOS 7` as the Base SDK and as the Deployment Target. The supported architectures are `arm64, armv7, armv7s`. The required device capabilities are `armv7`. The targeted device familiy is `iPhone`.

I also use the key `Application requires iPhone environment` with the value `YES`, but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW2) says that this key might not be the cause:

> If this key is set to YES, Launch Services allows the app to launch only when the host platform is iOS.

The app has all the required app icons and launch images in retina quality for 3.5 and 4 inch devices.

Am i missing something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After getting a real device I figured the mistake out:

I used the key `Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)` but for the iPod you have to use the key `Main storyboard file base name` in the application plist.

I hope this information is helpful for others who got this problem.

Comment: I made this mistake and was losing it trying to figure out why the iPod hated me. Thanks!